# C#/.NET: In need of a few (de)compression libraries

Tags: c#, .net, compression, libraries

My Google-Fu seems to be weak today. I've so far been able to find libraries for ZLib and BZip2 (SharpZipLib), and LZMA (7-Zip), but not Huffman, IMA ADPCM, and SPARSE.

Does anyone know of any pure .NET libraries that can handle these compression methods?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Huffman_algorithm.aspx) for Huffman...